docker fail to pull training/webapp
Why can't I find the training/webapp image without error, only a notice ?
When I pull training/webapp, it shows:
docker pull training/webapp
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from training/webapp
[DEPRECATION NOTICE] Docker Image Format v1 and Docker Image manifest version 2, schema 1 support is disabled by default and will be removed in an upcoming release. Suggest the author of docker.io/training/webapp:latest to upgrade the image to the OCI Format or Docker Image manifest v2, schema 2. More information at https://docs.docker.com/go/deprecated-image-specs/

Running docker images does not list the training/webapp image.
Using the arg --platform amd64 fails as well.

What do you mean by "failing to find"?

my fault, fail to find, my english is not good

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also include the full and exact error message that you're facing

ok，i will post a picture

@wangwang No, not a picture. Add text to your question.

@AymDev, Thanks for your help, this is my first time to post, is there any tourial for the format out?

@wangwang Read The Tour, how to ask and why you should not use images of code.
